Logical condition equivalent with restrictions
I am developing an Azure DevOps custom task. Part of the setting of the inputs is a VisibleRule which can contain a condition which will determine if the input will be visible, if the condition is evaluated to true.
Up until now, one of the conditions was:
"Property1 = Value1 || Property2 = false"

Property1 can have multiple values of Property{i}, and Property2 is either true or false.
Now there was a new value added to Property1 - Value5. And the condition should now evaluate to true only if Property1 is not Value5 and if it's the same as before. Meaning that my desired condition should have been something like this:
"Property1 != Value5 && Property1 = Value1 || Property2 = false".
The problem is that VisibleRule has restrictions:

No parentheses are allowed
Conditions may only have either && or ||, but not both.

What condition can I set which is both equivalent to the original condition "Property1 != Value5 && Property1 = Value1 || Property2 = false" and also follow the restrictions?

You mean an Azure DevOps custom task? Azure != Azure DevOps.

Yes Azure devops

So your comment was only meant for a simple edit?

My comment was meant to add clarity to your question by editing the post and fixing the tags. You fixed the tag after my comment, so I just edited the question.

Was hoping you could also answer the question itself if you know the answer

Unfortunately I can't help with this issue - I never created custom Azure DevOps tasks.
